# Material ui use palette primary color based on selected theme mode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

While using mui react, I want to color some non material ui custom components made with div using colors from my theme's primary palette.

I currently can use `theme.palette.primary.main` or the `.light` colors directly, including the `theme.palette.text.primary` for texts colors.

**But** if I change the theme to dark mode, I will have to change the color reference as well, by checking on `theme.mode` with conditionals like the following:

```
  <div
    style={{
      backgroundColor:
        theme.palette.mode == "light"
          ? theme.palette.primary.dark
          : theme.palette.primary.light
    }}
  >
    Test
  </div>
```

So is there a way we can make this work just like in the material ui components? Passing `theme.palette.primary` will work with theme mode changes?

Maybe something simpler like:

```
<div style={{ backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary }}></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) to save your theme setting globally and also you need to separate the themes like `light` and `dark`.

```
// SettingsContext.js
import React, {
  createContext,
  useState
} from 'react';

const defaultSettings = {
  // you could add sort of global settings here
  theme: 'light'
};

const SettingsContext = createContext({
  settings: defaultSettings,
  saveSettings: () => {}
});

export const SettingsProvider = ({ settings, children }) => {
  const [currentSettings, setCurrentSettings] = useState(settings || defaultSettings);

  return (
    <SettingsContext.Provider
      value={{
        settings: currentSettings,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </SettingsContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const SettingsConsumer = SettingsContext.Consumer;

export default SettingsContext;
```

You can build the settings context as a hook but you can skip this.

```
// useSettings.js
import { useContext } from 'react'; 
import SettingsContext from './SettingsContext';

const useSettings = () => useContext(SettingsContext);

export default useSettings;
```

And then try to create your custom theme which includes the dark and light mode.

```
// theme.js
import { createTheme as createMuiTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';

const themes = {
  'light': {
    ...
  },
  'dark': {
    ...
  }
];

export const createTheme = (name) => {
  return createMuiTheme(themes[name]);
}
```

After that, you need to pass the theme which you have selected in `App.js` or `index.js` whatever top level file.

```
// App.js
...
import { ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';
import useSettings from './useSettings';
import { createTheme } from './theme.js';

const App = () => {
  const { settings } = useSettings();

  const theme = createTheme(settings.theme);

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      ...
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};

export default App;
...
```

That's all.

Now you can use the selected theme without conditional render in your components.

```
<div style={{ backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary }}></div>
```

But this will not prevent the selected theme after hard refresh.

So if you want to keep the theme as selected even after refresh your browser, then you could save the theme setting in the [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

Comment: Thank you, So, does this mean the `mode` variable in `theme.palette.mode` is useless? Because, it works anyways if we set it either to light or dark in your code. right? or what is its use?

Comment: @Abraham, Yes, it works. But what is useful is to set palette for each theme separately. It will make your codes simple and readable and in reality a user could change a theme manually.