# Is It Best Practice To Use MUI 5 ThemeProvider Only in "_app.js" or Is It Ok To Use On Every Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

MUI 5 newbie question concerning ThemeProvider. Looking at the documentation at https://mui.com/customization/theming/ I see several examples, such as the one provided below, where a custom themed material component is wrapped with ThemeProvider in order to apply custom styles.

```
export default function CustomStyles() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <CustomCheckbox defaultChecked />
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

I've also seen examples where ThemeProvider is used in "_app.js" to apply custom theme styles globally, as shown below.

```
export default function MyApp(props) {
  const { Component, emotionCache = clientSideEmotionCache, pageProps } = props;

  return (
    <CacheProvider value={emotionCache}>
      <Head>
        <title>My page</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, width=device-width" />
      </Head>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <Header />
        {/* CssBaseline kickstart an elegant, consistent, and simple baseline to build upon. */}
        <CssBaseline />
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </ThemeProvider>
    </CacheProvider>
  );
}
```

I'm really confused as to which of the two is best practice, maybe the answer is both. Is it safe to say that I would generally want to put all of my global theme styles in my ThemeProvider wrapper that is applied to "_app.js" but for any one-offs or custom styling applicable to a specific component it is then safe to wrap the specific component with yet another ThemeProvider wrapper to apply the custom styling specific to that component? I just feel like I'm using ThemeProvider over and over again for custom components and it doesn't feel right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use [ThemeProvider](https://mui.com/customization/theming/#theme-provider) in the top level of a React app once even though it could be multiple and nested.

Let's say your app has a setting which can select your custom theme like 'light' or 'dark'.

In this case, you need to toggle a selected theme, which can be from React [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).

```
// src/App.js
...
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material';
const theme = createTheme(themeOption);

return (
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <Router>
      <Route>...
    </Router>
  </ThemeProvider>
);
...
```

Please have a look if you want to know more.
[Material ui use palette primary color based on selected theme mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70172354/material-ui-use-palette-primary-color-based-on-selected-theme-mode/70172883#70172883)

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Would your advise apply to any ReactJS project, including a complex admin dashboard? I ask because I have a component which I need to dynamically change the style based on state which would be simpler to achieve if the style lived in the component vs higher up. I've also encountered some die-hard react devs who insist that component specific CSS should live in the component itself. Even NextJS enables you to style individual components by creating a companion , such as "components/MyButton.module.css", which contains all of the "MyButton" custom CSS.

Comment: I don't have any reference to a kind of thing, but I am building a public repo to share my fully responsive layout with custom themes. You could look into my gist though. https://gist.github.com/hotcakedev628/e80492813952c9640ff4d77580c6fe26

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I just took a quick look and I like the way you organized it. Well done. I will explore it more and hopefully get some ideas on how to best implement my styling structure.