# Next.js Material UI (MUI) how to set Dark Mode with local storage

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, next.js

I am trying to get dark mode working in a Next.js app with MUI. The problem is that I cannot seem to get dark mode persistent once it has been set. I am setting the state with the help of `createContext` since the toggle button is inside a component.

When toggling it sets the state to either true or false and sets it in the `localStorage`.
However, on page refresh it goes back to a false state.

I have tried many solutions but cannot seem to get it to work.

At the moment I am doing the following within `_app.js` *(this is merely a snippet, full code in link)*:

```
  const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const mode = localStorage.getItem("mode");
    // set mode
    setDarkMode(mode);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("mode", darkMode);
  }, [darkMode]);

  // Set dark mode based on media query
  const prefersDarkMode = useMediaQuery("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)");
  useEffect(() => {
    setDarkMode(prefersDarkMode);
  }, [prefersDarkMode]);

  <ColorModeContext.Provider value={{ darkMode, setDarkMode }}>
    <ThemeProvider theme={darkMode ? darkTheme : theme}>
      {/* CssBaseline kickstart an elegant, consistent, and simple baseline to build upon. */}
      <CssBaseline />
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </ThemeProvider>
  </ColorModeContext.Provider>
```

I have setup a CodeSandbox with the **full** code:

https://codesandbox.io/s/next-js-mui-dark-mode-n6l24?file=/pages/_app.js

Any help here would be appreciated!

Comment: Please try to pass the `darkMode` from local storage rather than use just false as default. Like `useState(isDarkMode || false);`

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply. Care for a more extensive example?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70211208/mui-dark-mode-and-light-with-custom-palette/70211972#70211972 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70172354/material-ui-use-palette-primary-color-based-on-selected-theme-mode/70172883#70172883

Answer (score 1):

The third effect in your code `setDarkMode(prefersDarkMode)` will overwrite the `darkMode` in all cases, making any value from the **local storage** ineffective.

Moreover, it is better to define a custom `setDarkMode` function and pass it to the `ColorModeContext` provider.

```
  // Set dark mode based on media query
  const prefersDarkMode = useMediaQuery("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)");
  
  // use the media query setting as the default (which can be overwritten)
  const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = useState(prefersDarkMode);

  useEffect(() => {
    const mode = localStorage.getItem("mode");
    // set mode
    console.log(`get localStore ${mode}`);
    if(mode !== null){
        setDarkMode(mode  === "true");
    }
  }, []);

  // set DarkMode triggered by user
  const _setDarkMode = (newmode) => {
    console.log(`set localStore ${newmode}`);
    localStorage.setItem("mode", newmode);
    setDarkMode(newmode);
  };

  return (
    ... 
    <ColorModeContext.Provider
        value={{ darkMode, setDarkMode: _setDarkMode }}
    >
        ...
    </ColorModeContext.Provider>
    ...
  );
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/next-js-mui-dark-mode-forked-ucpvo?file=/pages/_app.js

Comment: Nice, thank you! The downside though,  is that `useMediaQuery("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)")` is not working anymore.

Comment: @Mark There is no easy way to this problem. Initially, when local storage is NOT set, `useMediaQuery` can be used to set the initial value of darkMode. However, once the user set a value in the local storage, there exist two places of configuration, which might conflict each other.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned, `darkMode` should not be just `false`, try to get the `darkMode`from local storage first and then use it as a default value.

Here's one of my repo.
https://github.com/hotcakedev628/mail-app-demo/blob/master/src/contexts/SettingsContext.js

Answer (score 0):

There is an error with your csb, does not load properly. In case you want to persist dark mode and without flashing problem on MUI. Must use next-themes, easy to set up and I did follow this method https://github.com/DiMatteoL/buzzrank-tutorial and live preview https://buzzrank-tutorial.vercel.app/.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33422353)